# Elasticsearch - treat symbols as regular strings AND make text case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, whitespace, tokenize, case-sensitive, analyzer

I have an elastic query like this:

```
return {
    url: API,
    data: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [{
                    function_score: {
                        query: {
                            multi_match: {
                                query: "1234-ASDasdfasdf",
                                // analyzer: "whitespace",
                                type: "best_fields",
                                fuzziness: "1",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    // filters are pushed into here
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our business data involves dashes, and I found that whitespace analyzer works best to escape dashes and treat them as regular strings.

However, whitespace analyzer messes up case insensitive searches.

I have not found a solution that allows case insensitive AND ignores symbols. With default analyzer, all symbols are treated as tokenizers I think. So entering something like 1-2-3-4 will actually search [1,2,3,4].

Is there a solution that is case-insensitive AND tokenizes on spaces (or atleast doesnt tokenize symbols)?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

If white space tokenizer works for you, but the problem is case-insensitive, then you can add `lowercase token filter`

[Refer an example with whitespace tokenizer and lowercase filter - custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html#analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter-analyzer-ex)

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/lowercase_example?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "whitespace_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

As you need to change the mapping of your data, please do not forget to reindex the data.